# Run command based on IP address received

Tags: linux, bash, python, dhcp, ip-address

I'm looking at if I can have a bash/python script that triggers a command based on the IP address Linux has received via DHCP.

e.g.

- DHCP received:  10.50.10.51 /24   runs command XYZ
- DHCP received:   10.50.20.84 /24   run command XYZ02

Is this possible to do and what would the command be. I'm thinking it prob basic with a variable on reading IP address, but not sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your DHCP client.

For example, `dhclient` has the option `-sf`:

> -sf script-file
>   Path to the network configuration script invoked by dhclient when it gets a lease.

Many other DHCP clients also have options to call scripts. There you can examine the address and do what you want.

Comment: my DHCP client is a raspberry Pi running Debian.

Comment: @Roa872: No it's not.  Raspberry pi is hardware and Debian is a linux distribution.  Neither are DHCP clients.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 

$result = `dhclient -v 2>&1 | grep bound | cut -d' ' -f3`;
chomp($result);

if ($result eq '10.50.10.51') {
    `echo doing XYZ`;
}   
elsif ($result eq '10.50.20.84') {
    `echo doing XYZ02`;
}   
else {
    print "[$result]\n";
}
```

You must run the script with `sudo` because `dhclient` requires elevated permission

```
sudo perl script.pl
```